# I don't understand how the adjoint operator is used in a book that I'm reading

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems

I'm reading [Stochastic Differential Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642161933) and don't understand what the authors do in [Chapter 2.3.1](https://books.google.de/books?id=yqlcgl3KumQC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22First+we+explain+some+generally+used+notation%22&source=bl&ots=xF86rjcwWB&sig=QxnyX8r01kehyuCIvZqiQh7mCBY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV24m904HNAhXqKMAKHQTXBdwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22First%20we%20explain%20some%20generally%20used%20notation%22&f=false). Let me introduce the necessary objects: Let

- $K$ and $H$ be real Hilbert spaces
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $K$
- $K_Q:=Q^{1/2}K$
- $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $A$ to $B$

> The authors state that with $\phi\in\operatorname{HS}(K_Q,H)$ and $\psi\in H$, we've got $\phi^\ast\psi\in\operatorname{HS}(K_Q,\mathbb R)$, where $\phi^\ast$ denotes the adjoint of $\phi$.

That doesn't make any sense to me. By [definition of the adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces), $\phi^\ast$ is a bounded, linear operator from $H$ to $K_Q$. So, we should have $\phi^\ast\psi\in K_Q$.

I've noticed that the authors use a different definition of the adjoint which is introduced in [Chapter 1.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=yqlcgl3KumQC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22again+a+Banach+space+under+the+supremum+norm%22&source=bl&ots=xF86rjcBZz&sig=EmHBjn3Z5stNVwbYoD3Zcy-U9WQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUldq41YHNAhUHdCwKHcmKCEMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22again%20a%20Banach%20space%20under%20the%20supremum%20norm%22&f=false). With that definition, $\psi^\ast$ is a bounded, linear operator from $H'$ to $K_Q'$, where $A'$ denotes the topological dual space of $A$. [This definition of the adjoint is usually been used for operators between Banach spaces; I don't understand why they use it here].

However, that still doesn't make sense to me. I don't even see that $\phi^\ast\psi$ is a well-defined expression.

> So, what do the authors mean?

Comment: I think he meant $\psi^* \phi$ (and not $\phi^* \psi$) is an operator $K_Q \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. for any $u \in K_Q$ : $u \mapsto \psi^* \phi u$.  and since it is bounded and of rank $1$, it is trivially Hilbert-Schmidt

Comment: and by definition the adjoint of $T : X \to Y$ is 
 an operator $S : Y' \to X'$ such that $y(T(x)) = S(y)(x)$ for  every $x \in X, y \in Y'$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_unbounded_operators_between_normed_spaces

Comment: @user1952009 How do you define $\psi^\ast$? $\psi$ is not an operator ... And could you please explain what you're targeting with your second comment?

Comment: if $\psi \in H$ then $\psi^* \in H^*$ i.e. it is an operator $H \to \mathbb{R}$. and since $\phi : K_G \to H$ we get $\psi^* \phi : K_G \to \mathbb{R}$ and voila. and with my second comment I said that the adjoint is defined in the same way in Banach spaces or Hilbert spaces, the main difference being that $H' = H$ when it is an Hilbert space, letting us define the adjoint as $\langle Tu,v \rangle =\langle u,T^*v \rangle$, but it is the same definition as in Banach spaces

Comment: @user1952009 You say $\psi^\ast\in H$. Then you say $\psi$ is an operator $H\to\mathbb R$. What is the formal definition of $\psi^\ast$?

Comment: I said $\psi^* \in H^*$ OF COURSE (or $H'$ as you want it's the same)

Comment: @user1952009 But how is $\psi^\ast$ defined? Maybe $\psi^\ast:=\langle\;\cdot\;,\psi\rangle$?

Comment: yes of course. a bounded linear operator $H \to \mathbb{R}$ (it is more $\psi^*(u) = \langle \psi,u \rangle$, in real Hilbert spaces $\langle.,.\rangle$ is symmetric but not in complex ones)

Comment: and you should read 3 books/courses in the same time (plus the forum) instead of being stuck on those kind of details

Comment: @user1952009 It depends on the definition of an inner product. I'm using the one where $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ is linear in the first and semilinear in the second argument.

Comment: right, I used it too, until I find on this forum everyone uses the other :) wiki says nobody agrees on that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: @user1952009 Did you take a look at [Chapter 2.3.1](https://books.google.de/books?id=yqlcgl3KumQC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22First+we+explain+some+generally+used+notation%22&source=bl&ots=xF86rjcwWB&sig=QxnyX8r01kehyuCIvZqiQh7mCBY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV24m904HNAhXqKMAKHQTXBdwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22First%20we%20explain%20some%20generally%20used%20notation%22&f=false)? It's plausible to think that the authors made a mistake. But if it is a mistake, they make the same mistake over and over again.

Comment: @user1952009 For example, they talk about the process $\Phi^\ast\Psi$ with $\Phi$ being $\operatorname{HS}(K_Q,H)$-valued and $\Psi$ being $H$-valued. And they obviously use such a process in Theorem 2.9. Any idea?